# Static library gcc - library not found

Tags: makefile, static-libraries, gnu-make

I want to create static library and something goes wrong. I have makefile:

```
static: main.c tree.c
    gcc -c -Wall tree.c -o tree.o
    ar crs libtree.a tree.o
    gcc -Wall -static main.c -L. -ltree -o main
    ./main
```

When I write "make static", it shows me:

```
gcc -c -Wall tree.c -o tree.o
ar crs libtree.a tree.o
gcc -Wall -static main.c -L. -ltree -o main
ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [static] Error 1
```

It created files: tree.o and libtree.a. I don't know why it doesn't want to find a library. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: That snippet cannot generate this error-message! Read both **very carefully**. And that's apparently not gcc and not related to C.

Comment: Edited. Now it's correct. Sorry.

Comment: Editing what you posted is not the way. You should provide a [mcve] and the actual output!

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, your system is not set up for static linking. Most newer Linux distributions aren't as static linking is highly discouraged.

Look for a package named `glibc-static` or similar and install.

In case your system is not Linux (could be MacOS X as well, you didn't state that) - You're doomed. Static linking is not supported on that platform at all.

Comment: I use macOS and I think it's not set up for static linking as u sad.